# Insert figure into uipanel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, tabs, figure

I have a parent figure on which I placed tabs with uitabgroup.  Each tab contains two panels.  Each panel has an axes handle.  I want to be able to print plotted results from either panel on any tab.  Is it possible to insert a figure object into the panel with something like:

```
hTabGroup               = uitabgroup('Parent', parent); 
% parent here is the main GUI figure as gcf passed in
set( hTabGroup, 'position', [ 0.35, 0.005, 0.6, 0.234] );
hTabs(1)                = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'A');
hTabs(2)                = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'B');
hTabs(3)                = uitab('Parent', hTabGroup, 'Title', 'C');

panelA              = uipanel('Parent',hTabs(1),...
    'Position',[0.00    0.0050    0.500    0.9750], ...
    'Title', 'fuel burn vs. distance' );

panelB                 = uipanel('Parent',hTabs(1),...
    'Position',[0.50    0.0050    0.500    0.9750] );

panelAxesA                = axes( 'Parent', panelA );
set( panelAxesA, 'position', [0.100    0.25    0.85    0.7 ] );

hFig = figure('Menubar', 'none');
```

Can I make hFig a 'child' of panelA?

Answer (score 0):

A [`figure`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) object can only have a [root object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) as its [parent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e288549).

Comment: I figured that would be case for the 2nd reply. I want to be able to print the graphic on the panel, as with File/Print or File/Save or File/Save As, which are commands from the top (parent) object on the Figure command bar.

Comment: @BenjaminLevy: If I understand you correctly, it sounds like, when you select a menu option (like "File/Print") of the parent window, you want it to perform that operation on *only* the axes of the currently active panel, and not on the whole figure?

Comment: That is correct.  I have a complicated parent gcf and many panel/panel axes.